# automatically detecting external calls from java

Tags: java, findbugs

I work for an enterprise that has a many millions of lines of Java code base.  Unfortunately, there were very poor practices put in place to track when one java EAR calls another EAR on another system.  The problem gets even worse, we run DB2 and all the DB2 schemas run on the same data connection.  This means there is no standard way to look at a config file or database connection to even tell what databases the application accesses.  This problem extends to other REST services, since we have REST data services, MQ systems, JMS, EJB RMI, etc.  Trying to do impact analysis is a nightmare.

Is there a tool that exists, maybe a findbugs plugin, that I can run on an application and have it generate a report of the systems that the application accesses?

If not, if I put say TRACE on the java.io and java.nio to log everything, should that capture any network connections that Java attempts to make thru the app server?

My ultimate goal, if i can't find a static analysis system that can help with these problems, i would like to write some AOP app that would live between the EAR and WebSphere and log all outbound and possibly inbound connections to the EAR resources.

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky one ;-)

Findbugs can help you identify all communication related places in the java code. But you have to do some stuff for that:

1. Identify all kinds of connections you want to flag (e.g. DB connections, EJB communication, ReST client code ...)
2. If you have that you need to write your own findbugs plugin which detect those places. May sound complicated however depending on how many places you want to identify a versed developer can do that in 2-3 days I would guess. As starting point have a look at the sourcecode of the available bug patterns in findbugs, look for a similar one and use that as a starting point. There are also lots of tutorials in the web on how to write your own bug pattern...
3. Configure findbugs to only use your bug pattern and run it on your code base (otherwise all the other bugs will clutter the result especially if your codebase is this huge).
4. Findbugs will generate a report / show you all the "communication" places...